# How to stop breaking tables border when page is spliting?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, frontend

I want to have on my website cards with border made in CSS and showing 3 cards per column.
The problem is that i don't want to split cards. 
My CSS:

```
<style>
.card {
    border-style: ridge;
    border-width: 3px;
}
.card-deck{
    -webkit-column-count:3;
     overflow-wrap:break-word;   
}
</style>
```

[Cutted Cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAQW8.png)

How to stop spliting cards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `break-inside: avoid;` to .card element:

```
.card {
    border-style: ridge;
    border-width: 3px;
    break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you should be able to avoid that by using `break-inside: avoid;`  on `.card`, but unfortunately support for css columns is not great.

More info: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/break-inside/

Support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn